# What is the difference between Rashba spin-orbit coupling and Drsselhaus spin-orbit coupling?

Tags: condensed-matter

It is known that both Rashba and Dresselhaus SOC need to have an inversion asymmetry. what makes them distinctive.

Answer (score 2):

- Rashba spin-orbit interaction (SOI) is caused by the Structural Inversion Asymmetry (SIA) where an external electric field (or built-in electric fields in quantum wells) breaks the inversion symmetry of the crystal.
- Dresselhaus SOI is caused by the Bulk Inversion Asymmetry (BIA) where the crystal itself lacks an inversion center (e.g. Zinc Blende structures).

Here is a reference that explains how Rashba and Dresselhaus SOI are derived in semiconducting heterostructures using Kane model.

Fabian, J., Matos-Abiague, A., Ertler, C., Stano, P., & Žutić, I. (2007). Semiconductor spintronics. Acta Physica Slovaca. Reviews and Tutorials, 57(4-5), 565-907.